# How to turn an object whose each cell is a matrix into one single matrix / data frame in R?

Tags: r

I ran into a problem trying to do double bootstraps. Here is the code I have:

```
n <- 50

bs_confint <- function(data, alpha, B1, B2){
  data2 <- data
  data_t <- data[(floor(alpha * n) + 1):(n - floor(alpha * n))]
  data_tmean <- mean(data_t)
 
  bs_1 <- replicate(n = B1, expr = {
      data1 <- sort(sample(x = data2, size = length(data2), replace = T))
      mean_t <- mean(data1[(floor(alpha * n) + 1):(n - floor(alpha * n))])
      meanB2 <- replicate(n = B2, expr = {
          sample2 <- sort(sample(x = data1, size = length(data1), replace = T))
          mean(sample2[(floor(alpha*n)+1):(n-floor(alpha*n))])
      })
      var <- var(sqrt(n) * mean_t - meanB2)
      data.frame(mean = mean_t, var = var)
  })
bind_rows(lapply(bs_1, as.data.frame))
} 

bs_confint <- Vectorize(bs_confint, vectorize.args = "alpha")
```

When I call the function `bs_confint(data = rnorm(n), alpha = seq(0.05,0.45,0.05), B1 = 1, B2 = 5)`, I get the following output

```
$`X[[i]]`
[1] 0.10209223 0.03674655

$`X[[i]]`
[1] -0.22517013  0.01381762

$`X[[i]]`
[1] -0.35747589  0.04578838

$`X[[i]]`
[1] 0.2508139 0.0248463
```

The class of the output is

```
[1] "data.frame" "data.frame" "data.frame" "data.frame" "data.frame" "data.frame" "data.frame"
[8] "data.frame" "data.frame"
```

So, still the problem persists.

Comment: We can help you with a [MRCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please, edit your question to add the data for each of the variable in your function.

Comment: If `bs_1` is a list of matrices, you could turn each matrix in to a data frame and then "stack" them with `dplyr::bind_rows()`. In sum, this may look like this (to be inserted after your call to `replicate()`: `bs_1 <- dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(bs_1, as.data.frame))`   
You may want to check whether the variable names in the data frame make sense and maybe include a value for `.id` within `bind_rows` in order to identify the original elements of the list where your data in the data frame came from.

Comment: @benimwolfspelz I added the line you suggested to my code, but the problem still persists.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the problem. If the function as such runs correctly and you just want to make the output of the vectorized function a data frame, you have to use `bind_rows()` not within the function but on the output of the vectorized function, i.e. `bind_rows(bs_confint(...))`.

Comment: My experiments with your function show that 1. The function does not accept a vector of `alpha` values. 2. `bs_1` returns a 3-dimensional list. This was solved by `c(mean = mean_t, var = var)` and outputting `return(t(bs_1))` gives a matrix with 2 columns. 3. What output do you expect?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.